# Casual gamer age distribution

Tags: casual-games, demographics

What is the age histogram of people who play casual mobile games like Cut The Rope, Angry Birds and so on?

Comment: I don't think this has much to do with age itself. I think having money for a smartphone and spare time is the key here. Maybe it's safe to presume an eight year old doesn't have a smartphone and 50 year old people don't have interest.

Comment: Well, I know enough people aged 50+ who do have a smartphone or tablet (e.g. christmas present) and use it *mainly* for casual games (and email)

Comment: @Thomas: there actually are some stats here indicating age groups, wealth groups, region of the world, gender, choice of device, spending habits on apps, favorite dining locations, liked pages on Facebook, and so on for these kinds of games.  Obviously "having a mobile device" is necessary to play them; however, there are many people with a smart phone who don't play those kinds of games or use any third-party apps at all!  You can't accurately intuit about these things: use hard data or go home. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a source, i do not know if it can be trusted but it looks legit.
http://www.statista.com/statistics/246577/age-distribution-of-mobile-gamers/

To put the answer right here the largest group of mobile gamers have an age of 25 to 34 and represent 27% of the total.

2nd and 3rd are surprisingly older with 23% for 35-44 years and 18% for 45 to 54 years.

Only 16% of the ages of 18 to 24, but i am sure it would be significantly bigger if they would have count it from the age of 15.

Last but certainly not least we have the 55+ gamers representing 16%. Who would have expected that?

Answer (score 1):

Tracking the references in this Forbes Article: 
[New Report Details Demographics of Mobile Gamers Buying Virtual Goods](http://www.forbes.com/fdc/welcome_mjx.shtml)

The [MocoSpace study](http://www.factbrowser.com/source/mocospace/), as well as numerous others with similar data is available through Fact Browser.

Answer (score 1):

A [Flurry report](http://blog.flurry.com/bid/71993/Mobile-Freemium-Games-Gen-Y-Plays-but-Gen-X-Pays) shows an interesting pattern in freemium games - mostly younger people play (age groups 18-24, then 13-17), but older people pay (age groups 25-34, then 35-54).